# Custom channel based authentication with gRPC

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, basic-authentication, grpc

How can I do simple channel authentication with gRPC in dotnet?

I want to pass just the client machine name and the client service name during the channel connection, and then be able of getting those in the server once, as a way of identifying where are the request coming from.

I do not want to pass them as metadata in every call, and I do not want to implement an additional method for that. I have been taking a look to the documentation and trying to implement some abstract classes like `ServerCredentials` but I do not see how it would be done neither if it is even possible due some internal classes.

Of course I do not want to use SSL certs for this, neither OAuth2.

Comment: Authentication would typically imply having some mechanism of verifying the given identity; it sounds instead like you just want a way to attach a name/tag to your channel on the client side, and have the server automatically "trust" this information. If this is really what you want, metadata or a field attached to your request messages is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Auth Data in Metadata

Passing them in metadata one good solution. Take a look at [hpack](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/compression.html). Your header will be compressed, will take only a few bytes.

You cannot bind your auth data to the channel, as it is not guaranteed in HTTP/2, that the same TCP channel will be used for subsequent calls.

That said, I am still waiting for a proper example form the GRPC java team on Metadata based custom authentication.

## Stream-based authentication

Stream-based authentication is also an option in case you want to save auth data between subsequent calls of the same API. In my interpretation this it means, that you have to pass authentication data only in the beginning of a stream. Your StreamObserver can then save the authentication data and reuse it in subsequent `onNext()` calls. I use this approach, it works really well.

Example

```
service MyService {
  rpc myFunction(stream MyMessage) returns (stream MyResponse)
}
message MyMessage {
  string user = 1;
  string password = 2;

  int32 myMessageVariable = 3;
}
```

user / password should only be set in the first `onNext(myMessage)` call on the `requestObserever`.
This is also really efficient, because on the wire the stream is represented by the StreamId which is a single byte (depending on how many streams you have open at the same time).

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of using a C# stream observer with GRPC for this? I am struggling to find an example of how to do this and am fairly new to C#.

Comment: Sorry have not been using C# in the past decade :) From the example that I have found the implementation is not really similar to Java. Dev guys on gitter were really responsive, though. I would give that a try. - https://gitter.im/grpc/grpc