# NestJS - Metadata in grpc microservice

Tags: node.js, grpc, nestjs

I am looking for a way to authorize an rpc via NestJS grpc microservices. Basically I want to attach a token in the grpc client, which has to be validated by the grpc server. I found [this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/115), but I did not get where exactly `grpc.Metadata` pass as a second argument.

Comment: I need to do the same thing. Have you looked at the GRPC Client options? https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/interfaces/microservice-configuration.interface.ts I'm pretty sure this is what it is referring to as "Metadata". If you look at the credentials option and the gRPC documentation for Node I'm pretty sure these are the same thing https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html#nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to solve this. For sure not the most elegant solution, but it works for now. A simplified example:

```
// gRPC client
@Get(':id')
async call(@Param() params) {
    const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
    // add relevant data to the metadata object (e.g from request header)
    metadata.add('role', 'admin');
    return this.userService.findOne({ id: +params.id}, metadata);
}

// Service
interface UserService {
    findOne(data: {id: number}, metadata: grpc.Metadata): Observable<any>;
}

// gRPC server
@GrpcMethod('UserService', 'FindOne')
async findOne(data: UserById, metadata: grpc.Metadata) {
    const meta = metadata.getMap();
    // do something with the metadata...
    console.log(meta.role);
    const items: User= [
        { id: 1, name: 'User 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'User 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'User 3' },
    ];
    return items.find(({ id }) => id === data.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting but I think this is good for Authorization. Authentication should be done when the connection is established.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you for pointing out. I wanted to solve an authorization problem. I got confused and used the wrong word - sorry!

Comment: I think authentication can only be done on connection for streams. For RPC your solution is the only solution because in http/2 the initial connection is not guaranteed to be the same like websockets. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725167/custom-channel-based-authentication-with-grpc.